# Linking error: cannot find lDispatchStubs and lCoreFoundation when using -static-stdlib

Tags: swift

I have a project with hummingbird as a dependency that I would like to build into a statically linked excecutable.

When I build a release using the command `swift build --configuration release` with the "-static-stdlib" compilation flag I get this error:

```
Building for production...
error: link command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
/usr/bin/ld.gold: error: cannot find -lDispatchStubs
/usr/bin/ld.gold: error: cannot find -lCoreFoundation
clang-13: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
error: fatalError
```

My `Package.swift` looks like below. But I get the same error using the `Package.swift` of the official Hummingbirg [hello example](https://github.com/hummingbird-project/hummingbird-examples/tree/main/hello) (while adding the "-static-stdlib" compilation  flag):

```
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "nomnomnom",
    dependencies: [
        .package(url: "https://github.com/hummingbird-project/hummingbird.git", from: "0.15.2"),
        .package(url: "https://github.com/apple/swift-argument-parser", from: "1.2.3"),
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "nomnomnom",
            dependencies: [
                .product(name: "ArgumentParser", package: "swift-argument-parser"),
                .product(name: "Hummingbird", package: "hummingbird"),
                .product(name: "HummingbirdFoundation", package: "hummingbird")
            ],
            swiftSettings: [
                .unsafeFlags(["-Osize", "-whole-module-optimization", "-static-stdlib"])
            ]
        )
    ]
)
```

The verbose compilation log is quite long but can be seen in thie gist [here](https://gist.github.com/jonha892/9717803a086e7599eb6123d87e7776c8)

I use Ubuntu (WSL2). I assume that I'm missing some dependency.
But which one and how can I install it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can add the `-static-stdlib` argument to your Package.swift. I think you have to add it to your build command

```
swift build -c release -Xswiftc -static-stdlib
```